# Mac OS X install Xcode fail

Tags: xcode, macos

I try to install XCode on my macintosh HD but the App store returns me this error:

`Unable to finalize your purchase
 Xcode can not be installed on "Macintosh HD" because Mac OS X 10.11.5 or later is required.`

But I am running Mac OS X version 10.7.5, so i try to install XCode 4.4 via developer sit but it's a failure, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You should not try to install a version of Xcode more than one year old: you wouldn't be able to use it to publish on Store or to build many open source projects.

Comment: You can also try installing XCode from the command line using: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution ... i make the last update of OS and a can now install the last version of XCode